# unsigned integer types in stdint.h place no restriction on what can be stored within?

Tags: c

I have to refer to this page for stdint.h:

```
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdint.h.html
```

I was completely surprised to see that I could store a negative number within a 
variable defined as uint64_t type.  I had the notion in my head that an unsigned
data type would be always a positive number and that if I attempted to store a
negative number in there I would get an error.  The following surprised me :

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) { 

    uint64_t a_big_positive_number;
    unsigned long another_big_positive_number;

    if ( argc < 2 ) {
        printf ( "usage : %s some_integer\n", argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    a_big_positive_number = 0;

    a_big_positive_number = strtol( argv[1], (char **)NULL, 10);
    fprintf ( stderr, "%i : %s\n", errno, strerror(errno) );
    another_big_positive_number = a_big_positive_number;
    fprintf ( stderr, "%i : %s\n", errno, strerror(errno) );

    return ( EXIT_SUCCESS );

}
```

When I compiled that with full C99 pedantic flags I get a binary that does the 
following astonishing things :

```
$ ./boffo -12345
0 : Error 0
0 : Error 0
```

Really ?

I ran it within a debugger and I see that indeed yes, the uint64_t is perfectly
fine with having a negative number and near as I can tell I could stuiff any
64-bits I want in there :

```
(dbx) run -12345
Running: boffo -12345 
(process id 16270)
stopped in main at line 15 in file "boffo.c"
   15       if ( argc < 2 ) {
(dbx) step      
stopped in main at line 20 in file "boffo.c"
   20       a_big_positive_number = 0;
```

First I want to see where in memory ( on the stack I guess ) this var is :

```
(dbx) print &a_big_positive_number
&a_big_positive_number = 0xffffffff7ffff620
```

Great ... now get the argv[1] input string and convert it to a long integer :

```
(dbx) step                          
stopped in main at line 22 in file "boffo.c"
   22       a_big_positive_number = strtol( argv[1], (char **)NULL, 10);
(dbx) step
stopped in main at line 23 in file "boffo.c"
   23       fprintf ( stderr, "%i : %s\n", errno, strerror(errno) );
```

What do we have in memory now at that address ?

```
(dbx) x &a_big_positive_number / 4 x
0xffffffff7ffff620:      0xffff 0xffff 0xffff 0xcfc7
```

A negative number inside an unsigned 64 bit data type.  No error at all!

```
(dbx) cont                          
Reading libc_psr.so.1
0 : Error 0
0 : Error 0

execution completed, exit code is 0
(dbx) quit
```

So the question is, what is the purpose or value of the unsigned integers within
stdint.h when it seems as if I could have used a 64-bit bitfield or an array
of eight unsigned chars or any chunk of memory big enough?  Where is the value
here?  Portability ?

```
/************** COMMENT AFTER SEEING GREAT ANSWERS BELOW ************/
```

Great answers from folks below have educated me and I see that the stdint.h types
are portable across platforms and they allow for a much greater range of positive
integer values.  The interpretation of the data stored within the variable is 
something for me to deal with and not to expect my compiler or debugger to mystically
or magically know that we are only working with positive numbers here.

Actually, I think the safest thing to do is to stick with uint32_t which is in the
C99 standard and then do this to get a correct positive value in there :

```
 a_big_positive_number = (uint32_t) labs( strtol( argv[1], (char **)NULL, 10) );
```

To be super "belt and suspenders" safe I should check argv[1] myself before I accept
it.  Who knows, it may be negative or it may be garbage data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conversion of a signed integer type to an unsigned one is fully defined in C, and happens implicitly in `a_big_positive_number = strtol(…);`, as if you had written `a_big_positive_number = (uint64_t) strtol(…);`.

The 6.3.1.3:2 clause of the C99 standard applies:

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.

(in the context of converting from another type)

And the 6.5.16.1:2 clause says that conversion occurs on assignment:

> In simple assignment (=), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.

Regarding the value of `uint64_t`, I am not sure what you are asking. Type `uint64_t` is an unsigned type of exactly 64 bits. A `unsigned long long bf:64;` bit-field would not offer any guarantee of taking only 64 bits in memory, nor would an array of eight unsigned chars (and operators wouldn't work directly on the latter).

Comment: conversion of a signed integer type to an unsigned one?  However there was no conversion.  I still have a negative number within the uint64_t type object and the debugger output confirms this. I see no "conversion" happened at all.

Comment: @paullanken "negative" or "positive" and "signed" and "unsigned" (and types in general) - those are just conventions and are used by the compiler and the programmer at the high level. The thing is that your number will contain some bit pattern regardless of what its type was. Now you can interpret it as signed or unsigned, and you will seemingly get a different result - but that's really just a matter of how you want to interpret the raw memory contents denoted by a variable.

Comment: @paullanken If, in the debugger, you print the contents of an unsigned variable as a signed integer, you obtain a signed value. The debugger has no idea of the types of symbols and uses the types you indicate to it to interpret the contents of memory.

Comment: The legality of bit fields of type other than `_Bool`, `int`, `unsigned int`, or `signed int` is implementation-defined.

Comment: @H2CO3: Another way to look at it is that an object of a given type can only contain values of that type. Interpreting an object's representation as a different type (type punning) is tricky, and can easily cross into undefined behavior if you're not *very* careful.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the signed/unsigned types is not storage, it's about how the bit pattern is interpreted. An example:

```
long signedNumber = -1l;
assert(signedNumber < 0);    //Bit pattern 0xffffffffffffffff is interpreted as negative, so this succeeds.
unsigned long unsigendNumber = (unsigned long)signedNumber;    //same bit pattern ...
assert(unsignedNumber >= 0ul);    //... but interpreted as an unsigned, it's roughly 18e18.
```

Actually, addition, subtraction, and multiplication are the same for unsigned and signed numbers, the hardware does not care. It's just for some special operations like comparisons that the compiler needs to know, whether the first bit has to be interpreted as a sign bit or not.

Comment: again I just don't see the value here of the unsigned data type when I can just as easily stuff a negative number in there. There is no error or any warning flag anywhere ( errno? ) to tell me that you just shouldn't do that.  It looks like the unsigned data types in stdint.h are of no value.  What am I missing here?

Comment: The point is, that you have more positive numbers available when you use an unsigned type than with a signed one.

Comment: An unsigned number gives you twice the positive range. It also has rollover *well defined* (which signed numbers don't). If you need it to error, then add some explicit error checking. Maybe you want to allow/disallow 0, how should the language know? There are cases where this no-error behaviour is beneficial, for example image processing, encryption, finding limits, etc.

Comment: When you write `unsignedNumber >= 0` you are comparing expressions with a signed and an unsigned type. The values will be converted to a common type according to a dense set of rules that take up a couple of pages of the standard. You should write `unsignedNumber >= 0u` to make it clear that unsigned values are compared, or explain how these rules apply in this case.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Good catch! I changed the example accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: the light just went on. I did this `a_big_positive_number = (uint64_t) -1l;` and when I print that value I get 18446744073709551615U which is 2^64-1 and that makes sense given that the variable is full of 64-bits all set to 1.  So a negative one was stored in there but it is really just a big ( the biggest? ) 64-bit integer.  Ah ha .. very clever.

Comment: @cmaster Yes, I see that my (now fixed) typo didn't prevent you to understand my comment.

Comment: gotta love stackoverflow and I wish I had bit coins to pass around to people that write great answers and education like this. BTW : I don't know what assert() does so I have to go look that up.

Comment: `assert()` is a way of saying: "This expression is always true, please fail the program immediately should you get a false value for it during execution." It's usually used to check for data inconsistencies.

Comment: super cool .. that assert() thing is in Donald Lewine's book "POSIX Programmers Guide" and I just never saw a use for it. I guess calling abort() may result in a core dump .. not such a bad thing really.

Comment: Signed-to-unsigned conversion is defined in terms of values, not representations. The definition is certainly motivated by the way 2's-complement represents signed values, but conversions work the same way on system that use 1's-complement or sign-and-magnitude.

Comment: @paullanken: "*So a negative one was stored in there but it is really just a big ( the biggest? ) 64-bit integer."* -- Not quite. You simply *cannot* store a negative value in an unsigned integer. The negative value is *converted* to the unsigned type, yielding `18446744073709551615`, *before* it's stored.